# Mongo - How to index filter with sort

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm indexing this mongo query but it not work.

```
db.getCollection("users").find(
    { 
        "find" : "users", 
        "filter" : {
            "userSetting.url" : "michael.john"
        }, 
        "sort" : {
            "_id" : -1.0
        }, 
        "projection" : {
            "userSetting" : 1.0, 
            "user" : 1.0, 
            "isOnline" : 1.0
        }, 
        "limit" : 1.0, 
        "singleBatch" : true, 
        "batchSize" : 1.0, 
        "returnKey" : false, 
        "showRecordId" : false, 
        "lsid" : {
            "id" : BinData(4, "JdjijSjxxKahhh7dWf92w==")
        }, 
        "$db" : "manager"
    }
);
```

I indexed user.Setting.url and _id (-1) but it not use index

Do you have any way to index that?

Thank you

Comment: But your field name seems to be `userSetting.url` no? Can you add you schema as well?

Answer (score 0):

You are running the [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell method **[`db.collection.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)**  which expects two parameters, `query` and `projection` documents i.e. the correct method should be

```
db.getCollection("users").find(
    { "userSetting.url" : "michael.john" }, 
    {
        "userSetting" : 1.0, 
        "user" : 1.0, 
        "isOnline" : 1.0
    }
).batchSize(1).sort({ "_id": -1 }).limit(1);
```

I believe you are after the **[`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/#dbcmd.find)** command which can be issued by the **[`db.runCommand()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/#db.runCommand)** helper:

```
db.runCommand(
    { 
        "find" : "users", 
        "filter" : {
            "userSetting.url" : "michael.john"
        }, 
        "sort" : {
            "_id" : -1.0
        }, 
        "projection" : {
            "userSetting" : 1.0, 
            "user" : 1.0, 
            "isOnline" : 1.0
        }, 
        "limit" : 1.0, 
        "singleBatch" : true, 
        "batchSize" : 1.0, 
        "returnKey" : false, 
        "showRecordId" : false, 
        "lsid" : {
            "id" : BinData(4, "JdjijSjxxKahhh7dWf92w==")
        }, 
        "$db" : "manager"
    }
);
```